# WSO2 Aggregator with 2 HL7 messages

Tags: aggregation, wso2-esb

I am trying to aggregate the response of 2 services, both the responses are in HL7 format.
but after aggregation the first message is getting in the output.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

please find the HL7 responses and Proxy service.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Prescription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <identifier>
    <id value="t001"/>
  </identifier>
  <status value="active"/>
  <patient>
    <type value="Patient"/>
    <url value="test"/>
  </patient>
  <prescriber>
    <type value="Provider"/>
    <url value="Dr.Mathews"/>
  </prescriber>
  <medicine>
    <identification>
      <text value="Zintac"/>
    </identification>
  </medicine>
</Prescription></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>


    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Prescription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <identifier>
    <id value="t001"/>
  </identifier>
  <status value="active"/>
  <patient>
    <type value="Patient"/>
    <url value="test"/>
  </patient>
  <prescriber>
    <type value="Provider"/>
    <url value="Dr.John"/>
  </prescriber>
  <medicine>
    <identification>
      <text value="tantac"/>
    </identification>
  </medicine>
</Prescription></soapenv:Envelope></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Proxy service :

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="hospital" transports="https,http,jms,local" statistics="enable" trace="enable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="default"/>
         <class name="com.wipro.iSoVA.HL7Converter"/>
         <clone sequential="true">
            <target to="http://localhost:8280/services/lab1/">
               <endpoint name="lab1">
                  <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/lab1/"/>
               </endpoint>
            </target>
            <target to="http://localhost:8280/services/lab2/">
               <endpoint name="lab2">
                  <address uri="http://localhost:8280/services/lab2/"/>
               </endpoint>
            </target>
         </clone>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete xmlns:f="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" expression="//f:Prescription">
               <log level="full"/>
               <send>
                  <endpoint>
                     <address uri="jms:/finalreport?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules xmlns:f="http://hl7.org/fhir" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">                           
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>                           
         <default>application/xml</default>                  
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description></description>
</proxy>
```

In the log i can able to see both the messages are enriched
log:

```
    Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelo
pe xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><Pres
cription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <identifier>
        <id value="t001"/>
      </identifier>
      <status value="active"/>
      <patient>
        <type value="Patient"/>
        <url value="test"/>
      </patient>
      <prescriber>
        <type value="Provider"/>
        <url value="Dr.Mathews"/>
      </prescriber>
      <medicine>
        <identification>
          <text value="Zintac"/>
        </identification>
      </medicine>
    </Prescription><Prescription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <identifier>
        <id value="t001"/>
      </identifier>
      <status value="active"/>
      <patient>
        <type value="Patient"/>
        <url value="test"/>
      </patient>
      <prescriber>
        <type value="Provider"/>
        <url value="Dr.John"/>
      </prescriber>
      <medicine>
        <identification>
          <text value="tantac"/>
        </identification>
      </medicine>
    </Prescription></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2013-05-27 11:59:46,926]  WARN - TimeoutHandler Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:
7ef92f4b-7637-4ea7-a832-a7bc66a71d38; dropping message after global timeout of :
 6 seconds
```

Thanks in advance......